# Electron IPCMain can't access variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have an electron app with the main.js file written in a more oo style. When I send a request from the render process it arrives fine. The problem is that when it tries to call a method for a object it states that the object is undefined.

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu, shell, dialog, session, ipcMain, webContents } = require('electron')

class GUI extends BrowserWindow {
    /**
     * Generates a window
     * @param {number} width - The initial width of the window. Default 800
     * @param {number} height - The initial height of the window. Default 600
     * @param {number} minWidth - The minimum width the window can possibly be. Default 800
     * @param {number} minHeight - The minimum height the window can possibly be. Default 600
     * @param {string} backgroundColor - The background colour of the window. Default #FFF
     * @param {string} icon - The path to the icon. Default null
     * @param {string} indexFile - The path to the index file to be loaded. Default null
     * @param {Electron.Menu} menu - The menu that should be displayed. Default null
     */
    constructor(width = 800, height = 600, minWidth = 800, minHeight = 600, backgroundColor = '#FFF', icon = null, indexFile = null, menu = null){
        super({
            width: width,
            height: height,
            minWidth: minWidth,
            minHeight: minHeight,
            icon: icon,
            backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
            frame: false,
            webPreferences: {
                nodeIntegration: true,
                enableRemoteModule: true
            }
        })
        this.fullscreen = false
        this.loadFile(indexFile)
        this.webContents.openDevTools()
        Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu)
        
        
        
    }//Constructor
    closeWin(){
        if(this.webContents.isDevToolsOpened == true){
            this.webContents.closeDevTools()
        }
        this.close()
    }//Close
    minimizeWin(){
        this.minimize()
    }
}

//Called when electron has finished initialising
app.on('ready', () => {
    let mainWindow = new GUI(800,600,800,600,'#323233','./assets/logos/logo.png', 'index.html')
})
//Quit when all windows are closed except on macOS
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin'){
        app.quit()
    }
})
ipcMain.on('windowControl', (event, arg) => {
    console.log(arg)
    // var request = JSON.parse(arg)
    var request = arg
    console.log(request)
    console.log(request.window)
    if (request.window == 'mainWindow'){
        if (request.func == 'openPreferences') {
            let preferencesWindow = new GUI(800,600,800,600,'#323233','./assets/logos/logo.png','./html/preferences.html')
        }
        if (request.func == 'close'){
            mainWindow.closeWin()
        }
        if (request.func == 'min'){
            mainWindow.minimizeWin()
        }
        
    } 
    if (request.window == 'app' && request.func == 'exit' && process.platform !== 'darwin'){
        app.quit()
    }
})
```

The error that I get when I click on the close button:

```
 A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception: iN
ReferenceError: mainWindow is not defined
at IpcMainImpl.<anonymous>
(C:\Users\computronics\source\repos\DC-Model-Railway-Controller\source\desktop
client\main,js:111:13)
at IpcMainImpl.emit (events.js:223:5)
at WebContents.< anonymous> (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:173:8161)
at WebContents.emit (events.js:223:5)
```

My aim is to send requests to the main process from the render process and for these requests to be carried out. These requests include creating and closing windows. Minimizing windows and other requests.

An example message sent from the render process:

```
{window:'mainWindow', func:'close'}
```

Other info

```
Nodejs: 12.14.1
Chrome: 83.0.4103.122
Electron: 9,1.2
V8: 8,3.110,13-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10,.0.18362
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.on('ready', () => {
    let mainWindow = new GUI(800,600,800,600,'#323233','./assets/logos/logo.png', 'index.html')
})
```

You are defining the variable `mainWindow` inside of the anonymous listener function.
Try making the variable global, like this:

```js
var mainWindow;
app.on('ready', () => {
    mainWindow = new GUI(800,600,800,600,'#323233','./assets/logos/logo.png', 'index.html')
})
```

---

#### another possible solution:

```
if (request.window == 'mainWindow'){
    if (request.func == 'openPreferences') {
        let preferencesWindow = new GUI(800,600,800,600,'#323233','./assets/logos/logo.png','./html/preferences.html')
    }
    if (request.func == 'close'){
        mainWindow.closeWin()
    }
    if (request.func == 'min'){
        mainWindow.minimizeWin()
    }
        
}
```

replace `mainWindow` with `request.window`

```
if (request.window == 'mainWindow'){
        if (request.func == 'openPreferences') {
            let preferencesWindow = new GUI(800,600,800,600,'#323233','./assets/logos/logo.png','./html/preferences.html')
        }
        if (request.func == 'close'){
            request.window.closeWin()
        }
        if (request.func == 'min'){
            request.window.minimizeWin()
        }
            
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your first suggestion worked.